# The Stable Manifold Theorem Applications

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

**Definition:** Let $\phi_t(x)$ be the flow of the nonlinear system $x'=f(x)$. The global stable manifold of $x'=f(x)$ at $0$ is defined by: $$W^s(0)=\bigcup_{t\leq 0}\phi_t(S)$$
Where $S$ is a $k$-dimensional differentiable manifold tangent to the stable subspace $E^s$ of the linear system $x'=Ax$ where $A=Df(0)$ and $0$ is a hyperbolic equilibrium point.
Show that $W^s(0)$ is unique and invariant with respect to the flow $\phi_t(x)$ ; furthemore, for all $x\in W^s(0)$, $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \phi_t(x)=0.$$

Comment: The definition of global stable manifold seems to depend on a choice of $x$.  Is this intentional?  Since $x$ is used as a variable elsewhere, it might be better to use $x_0$ and make the dependence slightly more explicit.

Comment: Are you sure that's the definition you want? Wouldn't $W^s(0)=\bigcup_{t\leq 0}\phi_t(0)$ make more sense?

Comment: sorry, the correct wording is the same in the book of Lawrence Perko - Differential Equation and Dynamical System

Comment: I think you should mention the part that $S$ is a stable manifold (i.e. $\phi_t(S) \subset S$ for all $t \geq 0$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}\phi_t(x_0) = 0$ for all $x_0 \in S$). It's rather important.

Comment: The Hartman-Grobman's theorem can help you. For more detail you can see the book "Geometric Theory of Dynamical Systems"..

Comment: @Euler88 There is no relation to the Grobman-Hartman, since without further hypotheses it only gives information on a neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

If $S \subset W^s(0)$ and $S$ contains a $W^s$ neighborhood of $0$, then
$$
W^s(0) = \bigcup_{t \leq 0} \phi^t(S) \, , ~~~~~~ (*)
$$
where above we have set
$$
W^s(0) = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n : \lim_{t \to \infty} \phi^t(x) = 0\} \, .
$$

In this context, $S$ is often referred to as a *local* stable manifold at $0$. The following is a statement of the "local" version of the stable manifold theorem. Below we write $B(r)$ for the ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin.

**Local stable manifold theorem**. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be sufficiently small. Then, $W^s_{loc}(0) = \{ x \in B(\epsilon) : \phi^t(x) \in B(\epsilon) \text{ for all } t \geq 0 \}$ is a smooth manifold (as smooth as $\phi^t$) tangent to $E^s$ at the origin, and for any $x \in W^s_{loc}(0)$, we have $\lim_{t \to 0} \phi^t(x) = 0$.

This is proved in many books. See, e.g., [Vaughn Climenhaga's blog post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778951/notions-of-stability-for-differential-equations) for the proof in the case of hyperbolic fixed points of ODE.

Once it is known, it is straightforward to prove the identity ($*$). Assume $S = W^s_{loc}(0)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. The containment "$\supset$" follows on noting that if $x \in \phi^{-s}(S), s \geq 0$, then $\phi^{s} x \in S$ and so $\lim_{t \to \infty} \phi^t(x) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \phi^{t - s} (\phi^{s} x) = 0$ by the local stable manifold theorem. For the containment "$\subset$", let $x \in W^s(0)$. Then there exists $T$ such that $\phi^t(x) \in B(\epsilon)$ for all $t \geq T$. Setting $x' = \phi^T(x)$, it follows from the local stable manifold theorem that $x' \in W_{loc}^s(0) = S$, hence $x \in \phi^{-T} S$.

Answer (score 0):

Both properties are immediate from the definitions. Note that $S$ is unique is a sufficiently small neighborhood and so $W^s(0)$ is well defined, that is, the set $W^s(0)$ is independent of $S$. It is also invariant since $\phi_t(S)\subset S$ for all positive $t$.

The last property follows from the definition: indeed, for each $x\in W^s(0)$ there exists $t>0$ such that $\phi_t(x)\in S$ (by the definition of $S$) and so $\phi_s(x)=\phi_{s-t}(\phi_t(x))\to 0$ when $s\to+\infty$ (since this happens if and only if $t-s\to+\infty$.